# SQL joining 4 tables issue

Tags: sql, join, db2

I have four tables:

T1

```
ID   ID1   TITLE
1    100   TITLE1
2    100   TITLE2
3    100   TITLE3
```

T2

```
ID  TEXT
1   LONG1
2   LONG2
```

T3

```
ID1  ID2
100  200
```

T4

```
  ID4  ID2   SUBJECT
   1    200    A
   2    200    B
   3    200    C
   4    200    D
   5    200    E
```

I want output in this result format:

```
TITLE    TEXT   SUBJECT

TITLE1   LONG1    A
TITLE2   LONG2    B
TITLE3   null     C
null     null     D
null     null     E
```

So I made this query but it gives me much more results than it should be.On example titles asre displayed more times than just once etc.

```
SELECT 
    t1.title,
    t2.text,
    t4.subject
FROM t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
    INNER JOIN t3      ON t1.id1=t3.id1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t4 ON t4.id2=t3.id2
WHERE 
    t1.id1=100
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Your expectations are wrong.  You should be getting five rows in T4 for every row in T1.  Following the join logical carefully to see what you are doing.

Comment: could you show your actual output please?

Comment: wow, your tables are a complete mess - you need to get back to the drawing board

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I don't work with DB2. After some browsing through documentation I have found that DB2 supports [row_number()](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0401kuznetsov/index.html) and [full outer join](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.intro%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_fullouterjoin.htm), but I might easily be wrong.

To get rid of n:m relationship one has to build additional key. In this case simple solution is to add row number to each record in t1 and t4 and use it as join condition. Row_number does just that, produces numbers for groups of data defined by `partition by` in ascending sequence in order defined by `order by`.

As there is difference in number of records in t1 and t4, and it is unknown which one always has more records, I use full outer join to join them.

You can see [the test (Sql Server version) @ Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5aa4/1).

```
select t1_rn.title,
       t2.[text],
       t4_rn.subject
from
(
  select t1.id,
         t1.title,
         t1.id1,
         t3.id2,
         row_number() over(partition by t1.id1
                           order by id) rn
    from t1
   inner join t3
      on t1.id1 = t3.id1
) t1_rn
full outer join
(
  select t4.subject,
         t3.id1,
         t4.id2,
         row_number() over(partition by t4.id2 
                           order by id4) rn
    from t4
   inner join t3
      on t4.id2 = t3.id2
) t4_rn
  on t1_rn.id1 = t4_rn.id1
 and t1_rn.id2 = t4_rn.id2
 and t1_rn.rn = t4_rn.rn
left join t2
  on t1_rn.id = t2.id
```

This kind of work should definitely be done on presentation side of an application, but I believe that software you are using requires already prepared data.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
select t1.title,t2.text,t4.subject
from t4 
left join t3
on t4.id2=t3.id2
left join t1 
on t1.id1=t3.id1
left join t2
on t1.id=t2.id
where t1.id=100
```

Comment: Where t1.id = 100 turns the left join into an inner join. Add the condition to the ON clause instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your tables. Your last join does that to your output -just analyze your query. for every record from T1 you have every record from T4.

Comment: Sorry but I can not change my tables. They must be in that format

Answer (score 0):

Outer joins are guaranteed to replicate rows, instead of matching only the ones you need. You may want to look at this:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/

To understand what the join types are, and how you can use them.

You are looking for a list of subjects, with associated text and title, but this may not be unique; more than one null exist for each of the titles. You want to drive the join from table 4, and get a list of subjects, with associated titles for each.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your ouput it appears you want all subjects displayed. Knowing this you should first off build everything off this table.

```
SELECT columns
FROM T4
```

Next build up your inner joins.

```
SELECT columns
FROM T4 subjectTable
    INNER JOIN T3 mapTable
    ON mapTable.ID2 = subjectTable.ID2
```

When happy with them, add on your optional columns with the outer join.

```
SELECT columns
FROM T4 subjectTable
    INNER JOIN T3 mapTable
    ON mapTable.ID2 = subjectTable.ID2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 textTable
    ON textTable.ID = subjectTable.ID4
    LEFT OUTER JOIN T1 titleTable
    ON titleTable.ID1 = mapTable.ID1
WHERE
    subjectTable.ID = 100;
```